# Clojure - require a namespace that was declared in the repl

Tags: clojure, namespaces, read-eval-print-loop

Suppose I want to do something like the following in the REPL:

```
(ns a1)

(defn adder [a b]
  (+ a b))

(ns b1
  (:require [a1 :as a]))

(println (a/adder 1 2))
```

This works fine if the code is defined in files according to the namespaces declared. However, if we're doing it in the repl - then we get an error at this line:

```
(ns b1
  (require [a1 :as a]))
```

The error being:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate a1__init.class or a1.clj on classpath:   
clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:432)
```

Now I'm aware I could explicitly put the full name of the namespace in:

```
(println (a1/adder 1 2))
```

But I want to abbreviate my namespaces. (In case my namespace is 20 chars long or more).

What do I change to ensure that I can refer to different namespaces on the repl in an abbreviated fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` uses the function `alias` internally to do what you want:

```
(ns b1)
(alias 'a 'a1)
```